# How to format numerical type in Invoice Report (AR.64.10.00)

Tags: acumatica

In the Invoice Report (AR.64.10.00) I want to reformat numerical type according to the policy on the tax bill of Vietnam.

I only want to change the format for this report (AR.64.10.00)

Example:

**+ UNIT PRICE**: 987,654,00

-> change into: 987.654

**+ EXTENDED PRICE**: 2,962,962,00

-> change into: 2.962.962

**+ Sales Total:**
35,061,704.00

-> change into: 35.061.704

**+ Tax Total:**
3,506,170.00

-> change into: 3.506.170

**+ Total (VND):**
38,567,874.00

-> change into: 38.567.874

Thanks,
ITMan

Answer (score 0):

have tried typing in N3 in the format field (top right in properties window)